# Not able to work with GPS

Tags: android

I am new to android programming. I have a thread inside which I have requested the location updates. The problem is that the code in `onLocationChanged(Location loc)`never gets executed. Please explain how I can correct this.

```
public void run() {

    Looper.prepare();

        while (isMyServiceRunning()) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                Log.d("spt", "read status started");
                if ((Connectivity.isConnected(getApplicationContext()))) {
                    URL urlreadstatus = new URL("http://asd.fgh.com/status.txt");
                //  Log.d("spt",String.valueOf(URLUtil.isValidUrl("http://asd.fgh.com/status.txt")));
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(urlreadstatus.openStream()));
                    str = in.readLine();
                    if(!str.equals(null)){
                        Log.d("spt", str);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    Log.d("spt", "read status complete");
                } else {
                    Log.d("spt", "not connected");
                    break;
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                Log.d("spt", "IO exception");
                str = "11";
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(NullPointerException e){
                str="11";
            }
            if (str.equals(null)) {
                str = "11";             
            }
            if (str.length() == 1) {
                loststatus++;
                LocationManager l;
                l=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                provider = l.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
                l.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 400, 1, this);
                Log.d("spt", "lost status=1 requesting location updates");

            } else {
                loststatus = 0;
            }

        }

    }
 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("spt", "in loc changed");
        double longi = loc.getLongitude();
        double lati = loc.getLatitude();
        double acc=loc.getAccuracy();
        Log.d("spt", String.valueOf(acc));
        if (loststatus > 0) {

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://asd.fgh.com/writegps.php?value="
                            + String.valueOf(lati) + ","
                            + String.valueOf(longi));
            // output is the variable you used in your program
            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                Log.d("spt", "writing coord to file");

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(lati) + String.valueOf(longi),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post the error... from log-cat..

Comment: I am not getting any errors in this code.. but the onlocationchanged() method is not executing. @ManetiVinay

Comment: Do you have the permission set in the manifest?

Comment: Maybe str.length() never be == 1

Comment: first of all you are using criteria and not setting any criteria. Secondly as @ramaral said that might be the case. Thirdly, have you set the permissions in manifest? fourthly is gps on? fifth where are you running your app emulator or actual device?

Comment: in the logcat i can see that str.length==1 is satisfied..and I am running it on an emulator..I have fine and coarse location and network permissions ,gps is on, and though I am not setting any criteria..I am using the "gps" provider...

Comment: is there something wrong with the `Looper.prepare();` statement??

Comment: E/GpsLocationProvider(74): native_start failed in startNavigating()
 getting this in the logcat while turning on GPS in the Location settings

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a location Listener as follows, as apposed to implementing one in your class (which I assume you did in out-of-sight code):

```
private void setupLocationUpdates() {

    // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
    mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        // Called when the location has changed.
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            mLocation = location;
            // DO SOMETHING HERE
        }
      };
    mlocationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    // Register for location updates 
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mlocationProvider, 0, 0, mLocationListener);
}
```